# How to open a popup window via Firefox Addon contextual menu?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an extension for Firefox that needs to open a standard Javascript popup window that can be a custom size. I have looked all around and I can't seem to figure out how to do it. My code for a contextual menu works good, but it seems like Firefox is blocking the `window.open` snippet needed to accomplish this.

Is there a way todo it via XUL, or any other SDK modules?

Comment: Please add more detail, or ideally your code that doesn't work. Also, are you using the Add-on SDK? Are you trying to open a 'panel' created withe the SDK's panel module, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need a bit more details, here's what I think you're going for.

```
require("sdk/context-menu").Item({
  label: "Open Window",
  contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {' +
                 '  window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572412/how-to-open-a-popup-window-via-firefox-addon-contextual-menu");' +
                 '});'
});
```

This code would open up a new window (or tab) when the user clicks on the Open Window item.  The `window.open` function works in this context but I'm not sure what context you're not seeing it work in.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want open not a popup window but panel, here's an example:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var panels = require("sdk/panel");

var panel = panels.Panel({
    contentURL: self.data.url("panel.html")
    // , onHide: handleHide
});


require("sdk/context-menu").Item({
  label: "Open Window",
  contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {' +
                 '  self.postMessage(node.innerHTML);' +
                 '});',
  onMessage: function (data) {
    console.log('posted retrieved: '+data);
    panel.show();
  }
});
```

And some [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Display_a_Popup)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
`<popupset>
  <panel id="some">
  </panel>
<popupset>`
```

In the JavaScript write:

`document.getElementById('some').openPopup(...)`